# CSS classes that read like javascript object attr:val pairs

Tags: javascript, css

I ran across some unique css class attribute:value pairings in HTML tags. It looks like some custom JavaScript is interpreting this, but I have never seen this before. I saw this on [www.woothemes.com/flexslider/](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) (you have to view source to see the following)

```
   <pre class="brush: js; toolbar: false; gutter: false;">
```

Is this a custom library or javascript application that can be freely used?

Comment: Clarification has been added.

Comment: I don't see what you are talking about on your link.

Comment: View the source of the page and you can search for the exact block of code above.

Comment: This is what they are using. http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/configuration/ First google result if you type in the value of the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the source, it's the http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter that uses these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's from the syntax highlighter used there. So yes, some JavaScript is interpreting that. Actually, encoding key/value pairs in the `class` attribute was pretty common before HTML5 `data-` attributes.

Comment: I'll be damned. I learn something new all time.